# A local variable that is also a class variable

Tags: python

I am confused why Python throws the following error despite my simple class first declaring the class variable and then incrementing its value every time a new object is instantiated:

```
r = Robot("Rob")
population += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'population' referenced before assignment.
```

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here? Of course I should create my local variable (in this case, a class variable) before I modify it, so why is this a problem?

```
class Robot:

    ''' Represents a robot with a name! '''

    # A class variable.
    # Increments every time
    # an object of this class
    # is instantiated, so it
    # counts the instances.
    #
    population = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        population += 1
        print("Initializing {}".format(self.name) )


r = Robot("Rob")
```

Comment: Because `population` isn't a local variable *or* a class variable when you try to increment it. The class attribute is accessible via `self.population` or (probably better for your purposes) `Robot.population`.

Comment: `self.population += 1` would define a new instance variable, shadowing the class variable; `Robot.population += 1` is required here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, you need to explicitly reference the class attribute named `population`. While this could be done by hardcoding the class name, `Robot`,  into the increment statement, it can be avoided by referencing the class of the `self` argument.

This means the code in the method is no longer dependent on the exact class' name and doesn't have to be adjusted should that name ever be changed for some reason.

```
class Robot:
    population = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.__class__.population += 1  # Class name *not* hardcoded.
        print("Initializing {}".format(self.name) )

print('Robot.population:', Robot.population)  # -> Robot.population: 0
rob = Robot("Rob")                            # -> Initializing Rob
josh = Robot("Josh")                          # -> Initializing Josh
print('Robot.population:', Robot.population)  # -> Robot.population: 2
```

Comment: `self.__class__` isn't necessarily a reference to `Robot`, since `self` could be an instance of a descendent of `Robot`.

Comment: @chepner: No it's a reference to the class of the instance. Which is exactly the right thing to happen if the subclass hasn't defined it's own `population` attribute—so I think your presumed down-vote is unjustified.

Comment: The OP clearly wants to increment `Robot.population`, so be explicit. `self.__class__` is set for a reason, and that reason isn't to help lazy programmers change their class names on a whim. It isn't the job of `Robot.__init__` to modify the class variables of other classes.

Comment: @chepner: It's not laziness...it's called decoupling—you may have heard of it. Furthermore, I doubt the OP was thinking about subclasses of `Robot` when they wrote their question.

Comment: @chepner: I doubt it. If the subclass wants to have the class attribute `population` incremented every time a new instance is created, a call to the base class' `__init__()` written this way would increment either `Robot`'s attribute or the subclass' own depending on whether it defined a class-level one or not—which is likely _exactly_ the behavior most folks would want (and at least semi-expect).

Answer (score 0):

Assignments *always* create a local variable; the purpose of `global` and `nonlocal` statements is to override that behavior. However, you still need to access a class variable via a class, because a `class` statement does not create a new scope to which `nonlocal` could refer.

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    Robot.population += 1
    print("Initializing {}".format(self.name) )
```

Comment: Thanks chepner. So, every time I use a class variable in a class method, I have to prefix it with the class name?

Comment: Correct. (Technically, you can access it via `self` as well, but that depends on there not being an instance variable with the same name, and `self.population += 1` would create just such an instance variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Robot:

    ''' Represents a robot with a name! '''

    # A class variable.
    # Increments every time
    # an object of this class
    # is instantiated, so it
    # counts the instances.
    #
    population = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Robot.population += 1
        print("Initializing {}".format(self.name) )


print(Robot.population)
r = Robot("Rob")
print(Robot.population)
r = Robot("Rob")
print(Robot.population)
```

Execution output:

```
0
Initializing Rob
1
Initializing Rob
2
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain *why* this makes a difference.

Comment: Agree I should have added the why. Unless prefixed with self/object_or_class_reference, it's a local variable (unless declared as global via keyword global).

Comment: Yes, *I* know that (I commented as much on the question!) My point is you should *put it in the answer*.